# How to find and replace specific part of specific lines with sed?

Tags: sed, latex

I have a `LaTeX` file `foo.tex` that contains these lines:

```
\includegraphics[width=0.49\textwidth]{img1}
\includegraphics{img2}
\subfloat{\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{img3}}
\subfloat{\includegraphics{img4}}
```

I'd like to replace these lines in the file to add the file extension, to look like:

```
\includegraphics[width=0.49\textwidth]{img1.png}
\includegraphics{img2.png}
\subfloat{\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{img3.png}}
\subfloat{\includegraphics{img4.png}}
```

I started trying with `sed` in this command:

```
cat foo.tex | sed 's/\(includegraphics.*[a-z,0-9,\-]}\)/\1.png}/g' > bar.tex
```

But it returns:

```
\includegraphics[width=0.49\textwidth]{img1}.png
\includegraphics{img2}.png
\subfloat{\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{img3}.png}
\subfloat{\includegraphics{img4}.png}
```

How could I fix my `sed` command to add the file extensions?

### Edit

The image filenames are not only img1, img2, etc.

Comment: https://metacpan.org/pod/LaTeX::Parser

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ sed '/\\includegraphics/s/img[0-9]*/&.png/g' input
\includegraphics[width=0.49\textwidth]{img1.png}
\includegraphics{img2.png}
\subfloat{\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{img3.png}}
\subfloat{\includegraphics{img4.png}}
```

The regular expression for the replacement operation looks for `img` followed by any number of digits (including zero digits), and appends `.png` to the end of the match.

A slightly more robust version which will only perform the replacement *inside* curly braces:

```
$ sed '/\\includegraphics/s/{\(img[0-9]*\)}/{\1.png}/g' input
\includegraphics[width=0.49\textwidth]{img1.png}
\includegraphics{img2.png}
\subfloat{\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{img3.png}}
\subfloat{\includegraphics{img4.png}}
```

This looks for (for instance) `{img3}` on any line containing `\includegraphics`, extracts `img3` from it, appends `.png`, and re-wraps that in new curly braces, for the desired `{img3.png}`.

Comment: Sorry, but the image file names are not only img1, 2 and 3. I have all kind of names.

Comment: I just changed `{\(img[0-9]*\)}` to `{\([a-z0-9\-]*\)}`